# Swift delete struct array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, structure

I have a problem when using an array of struct.

I have this struct:

```
struct Group: Equatable {
    var date: Date
    var day: String
    var time: String
    var subgroup: String
    var type: String
    var subject: String
    var building: String
    var room: String
    var lecturer: String

    static func == (lhs: Group, rhs: Group) -> Bool {
        return lhs.date == rhs.date && lhs.day == rhs.day && lhs.time == rhs.time && lhs.subgroup == rhs.subgroup && lhs.type == rhs.type && lhs.subject == rhs.subject && lhs.building == rhs.building && lhs.room == rhs.room && lhs.lecturer == rhs.lecturer
    }
}
```

I add data to the struct array:

```
var groupModel: [Group] = []
```

And I use groupModel in a tableView for row and section. In the table, all is Ok.

But when I reload data in the table, I want to delete old data and put in new data.

I tried:

```
self.groupModel2.removeAll()
add new data to groupModel2
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

And in the table I get new data and old. How can I delete old and put only new data?

Comment: post whole context

Comment: other parts of your code is important. is your "numberOfRowsInSection" and "cellForRowAtIndexPath" functions use "groupModel2" array?

Comment: Unrelated but the `static func ==` testing **all** struct members is redundant in Swift 4. You get it for free when adopting `Equatable`

Comment: Why one is groupModel and the other is groupModel2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try

```
groupModel2 = []
```

if .removeAll() doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry for that. My reputation is less than 50 so I cannot comment. Will change the answer now.

Comment: no worries. I didn’t want to downvote as you did provide an answer. But also a comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Highly doubt the issue is with your array. .removeAll is pretty straight foreward.
You said you data is mixed. 
UITableView is highly effective in recycling old cells. Can it be possible, that your cell is not properly reset during prepareForReuse?